# How to use async-await in onsubmithandler

Tags: reactjs, async-await, axios

I put the login authentication function and navigation function in the onsubmitandler.
"/" requires a token value in the cookie so that it can go to the router.
But if you look at my code, it goes to "/" before the setCookie is executed and an error occurs.
I want to make sure that 'navigate ("/");' is executed after the setCookie is executed.

```
  const [cookies, setCookie, removeCookie] = useCookies("token");

 const onSubmitHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("nickname", Nickname);
    formData.append("password", Password);
    axios
      .post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API}/normal_login/`, formData)
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.data) {
          console.log(response.data.account_token);
          setCookie("token", response.data.account_token, {
            path: "/",
          });
          console.log("cookies", cookies); // null
        }
        navigate("/");
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log("==>", err);
      });
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

[useCookies](https://vueuse.org/integrations/usecookies/#options) does not have any [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) functions, however you can use a **addChangeListener**, and navigate when the cookie is changed. Though I suspect the real problem lies in your [deconstructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

Currently you are trying to deconstruct an array, but useCookies returns an object, so replace your [] with {}. If done correctly your deconstructor should look like the following.

```
const {cookies, setCookie, removeCookie} = useCookies("token");
```

If changing your deconstructor didn't work you could use the following example to solve your problem.

```
const {cookies, setCookie, removeCookie, addChangeListener} = useCookies("token");

addChangeListener( () => {
    navigate("/");
})
```